# installing Neo4j on AWS (instructions fail)

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j

I recently spun up a t2.micro image and I want to install neo4j on it. I started with the instructions at https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-cloud-aws-ec2-ami/. But I got to the step for creating a security group and I received an error that a region needed to be supplied. Here is the command I used:

```
aws ec2 create-security-group \
   --group-name $GROUP \
   --description "Neo4j security group"
```

The error message was

```
You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".
```

When I run this command I get prompted by a lot of stuff that don't seem related to region? Not only am I prompted for values that I don't know where/how to get them, when I am prompted for the region I am not sure the format to enter the region. So my question is how to I configure a security group so I can move on to installing neo4j on this instance?

There are still several steps to follow to install neo4j, but I seem to be tripped up on this step.

Answer (score 0):

The commands expect a default region under ~/.aws/config

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
output=json
```

On the link that you have shared, there is a step to "Configure the AWS CLI with Your Credentials". This step allows you setup aws profile(s) and as part of those profiles, you can set a region.

Follow this link to understand how you can setup your aws profile with credentials and region details

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html

Hope it helps

Comment: I guess the "error" was that I was redirected to 'aws configuration' when I was trying to establish a security group. Being new to AWS Cli, security groups, and configuration, I just didn't know if the instructions were wrong. Your input was very helpful. Thank you.